# issue clicking dropdown values from input

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait



wait = WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('website')

customerid_form_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-labelledby='i1']")
for form_element in customerid_form_elements:
    form_element.send_keys("test")

charge_input = input("Charge Amount: ")
form_charge = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-labelledby='i5']")
for charge in form_charge:
    charge.send_keys(charge_input)

user_input = input("Card & CVV '6969696969696969 666': ")
input_list = user_input.split()

text_field_1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-labelledby='i9']")
text_field_2 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-labelledby='i21']")
text_field_1.send_keys(input_list[0])
text_field_2.send_keys(input_list[1])

last_four_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-labelledby='i25']")
card_number = input_list[0]
last_four = card_number[-4:]
last_four_field.send_keys(last_four)

expiration_date = input("Expiration date (MM): ")

dropdown_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@jsname='LgbsSe']")
dropdown_element.click()

options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@jsaction and starts-with(@data-value, '[01]')]")

for option in options:
    if option.get_attribute("data-value") == expiration_date:
        option.click()
        break
```

Everything runs fine until it has to click the data value of my input from the dropdown. Cant use a selector because its a div class. pretty confused. See image for the jsaction values im trying to click based on my from input.

[HTML pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QInde.png)

Comment: `driver`....  presumably you are using selenium ?  please add imports or code such that it works or is relocatable.

Comment: added sorry complete code sorry about that!

Comment: From the URL you posted, I don't see those webelements in your code, is that URL correct?

Comment: @AbiSaran 
there ya go

Comment: @D.L
should be more comprehensible now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified some of your code, please try this:

for 'Customer ID' field, there is only one match for the locator, so you need to use `find_elements` and `for` loop, you can use this:

```
# for Customer ID field
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[aria-labelledby='i1']"))).send_keys("test")

# for 'Expiration Month' field:
expiration_date = input("Expiration date (MM): ")  # you have to enter the value in the format - '01' or '02'... 

dropdown_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@jsname='LgbsSe'])[1]")
dropdown_element.click()
time.sleep(2)   # increased the wait time

options = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".OA0qNb.ncFHed.QXL7Te .MocG8c.HZ3kWc.mhLiyf span")

for option in options:
    time.sleep(1)     # added wait time
    if option.text == expiration_date:
        option.click()
        break


# for Expiration Year field
expiration_month = input("Expiration Year (YYYY): ")  # you have to enter the value in the format - "2021" or "2022"...
time.sleep(1)
dropdown_element_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@jsname='LgbsSe'])[2]")
dropdown_element_2.click()
time.sleep(1)

options = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".OA0qNb.ncFHed.QXL7Te .MocG8c.HZ3kWc.mhLiyf span")

for option in options:
    if option.text == expiration_month:
        option.click()
        break
```

Comment: worked! it now selects the year correctly but sometimes it doesnt seem to get the month correct. its a almost 1 in 4 chance that it clicks the month (MM). still troubleshooting that. any ideas

Comment: Added some wait time, try with this, I executed this code more than 10 times continuously, and it works perfectly fine for me. What error you've got?

Comment: Figured it out! your code does work fine. for some reason it had to be on the same desktop screen within viewing. Ran in headless mode and its works great. Thanks a ton. P.S ill check the book out